# regular expression | add 3 characters at the end of a string

Tags: postgresql, text, bulk, string-aggregation

I have multiple queries which use string_agg function and we are migrating to a newer postgres version and this particular one needs now a delimiter, we need to add just this string *,''* to every single line where string_agg is used.

Here's one example of what we currently have:

```
string_agg('|'||mu_to.unit||(pa.measure*(mu.base_multiplier/mu_to.base_multiplier))::numeric||CAST(' ' AS varchar)||mu_to.unit_display)
```

It needs to end up like this:

```
  string_agg('|'||mu_to.unit||(pa.measure*(mu.base_multiplier/mu_to.base_multiplier))::numeric||CAST(' ' AS varchar)||mu_to.unit_display,'')
```

Then we have something like this:

```
string_agg('#attribute_'||attribute_id::varchar||':'||attribute) as attr
```

And it needs to end up like this:

```
string_agg('#attribute_'||attribute_id::varchar||':'||attribute,'') as attr
```

There are 67 reports in which these lines appear randomly and not always the same fields / tables names, so I'm looking for a way to change all at once and add the delimiter in bulk to not edit all 67 manually.
It would be something like find **string_agg(** look for the last parenthesis and add **,''**

I guess it will be some sort of search replace but not 100% sure how I could achieve this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

What are you using now? There has never been a released version of PostgreSQL in which the second argument to string_agg was optional.  (There was a time during development cycle of 9.0 where it was optional, but that was changed pre-release).  Are you really using a 10 year old dev version of PostgreSQL?

Maybe you have a user-defined aggregate named string_agg which takes one argument?  But in that case, why isn't your upgrade method re-creating it?

Comment: We're using postgres 8.4 and it seems this is not an user defined function. We just installed the newer version on a fresh server and we're migrating all the reports actually

Comment: I have a copy of 8.4.22 around, and there is no system-defined aggregate there for string_agg (you can see using \daS in psql).  Maybe you have some custom compilation which is not identifying itself properly.